# Visualizing Projections on Riemann Sphere

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, math-software, mobius-transformation, riemann-sphere

I am studying *Visual Complex Analysis* by Tristan Needham. I was using pen and paper as well as some 'python' code to visualize the 2D mappings like $z \rightarrow e^z$ but now I came across a question in the exercise where it says to project it on the Riemann sphere and observe the symmetry. Till now I was just imagining and drawing. I tried drawing it using 'python' but don't know which software to use to map it on the Riemann Sphere. I tried using online mapping softwares but they were not accurate.

Please suggest any software or site where I can experiment and learn the 3d mappings

Comment: Good to see others working through this book as well :-) I have gotten to differnetiation chapter. Also, hi from kerela! :D

Comment: Which software did you use to visualize stuffs in 3d? Nice to meet you. From Jharkhand

Comment: I skipped those since I didn't know much about computer animations but there is this one youtuber who has made videos on how the mapping works using some programs [check here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNp8Qf20-sA&list=PLiaHhY2iBX9g6KIvZ_703G3KJXapKkNaF&index=10). He goes into Rienman surfaces as well (which is not covered in Tristan)